# how can i make this text resize with the box

Tags: html, css

https://gyazo.com/fbcfb86757bb55d32b3cd3ac1a589bf6

also im a beginner so i may not know stuff that is basic to you guys and i may missed some very basic stuff

```css
 .card {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 #212226;
    transition: 0.3s;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 7;
    border: 1px solid #212226;
    display:inline-block;
    }

    .card:hover {
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 25px 0 #212226;
    margin: 9;
    }

    .container {
    padding-left: 4px;
    display:inline-block;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="card">
    <div class="container">

    <p><b>Number:&nbsp;&nbsp;+38526654165<br>Address:&nbsp;&nbsp;Kissakuja 123<b></p> 
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Hi! You want to break the line or resize the font size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I realized you want to enclose the box content with box itself. You can use CSS `word-break` for this.

```
p {
   word-break:break-all
}
```

This will break all lines of your texts.